# What is the reason of touch file in azure blob

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage

In azure blob, when a directory is created, one empty blob is also created with same name. Example, for each folder extract_date=2018-10-22, there will be a block blob with same name extract_date=2018-10-22 created.

What is the significance of this touch file and why is it created?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you manually creating these folders using Microsoft's Storage Explorer or these are created through some other process (may be a backup or something)? What kind of storage account in which you're creating the folder?

Comment: Yes, these files are copied by some backup process from different source. Not really sure on the kind of storage account. Where can i check that?

Answer (score 0):

Blob containers don’t really have folders.  Just files.  So without at least one file, the path wouldn’t exist at all.

Blob now supports folders and ACLs with the new Gen2 Azure Data Lake Store.

Comment: With that logic, shouldn't the file be in the folder instead of at the same level as that of the folder?

Comment: Since there are no folders, that’s just a UI design choice.  A container has an ordered list of blobs.  Period.